# Google Analytics not working on Android

Tags: android, analytics

I have added the following lines of code to my ZainApp extends Application class

> ```
>   synchronized public Tracker getDefaultTracker() {
>     if (mTracker == null) {
>       GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
>       // To enable debug logging use: adb shell setprop log.tag.GAv4 DEBUG
>       mTracker = analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_layout);
>        }
>     return mTracker;
>     }
> ```

Where global_layout is

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <resources>
> <integer name="ga_sessionTimeout">300</integer>
> <string name="ga_trackingId">UA-67435107-1</string>
> <bool name="ga_reportUncaughtExceptions">true</bool>
> </resources>
> ```

Then inside one of my activities I call the following in oncreate function

> ```
>         ZainApp application = (ZainApp) getApplication();
>         mTracker = application.getDefaultTracker();
>         mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
>         mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
> ```

I run my app , I go to my analytics page https://www.google.com/analytics/ , and check there is nothing. whats the problem? what am I missing?

Comment: you should cover your `ga_trackingId` for the question. otherwise everybody will be able to send stuff to your analytics.

Answer (score 0):

GoogleAnalyticsHits.java

```
public class GoogleAnalyticsHits {

private static final String PROPERTY_ID = "UA-XXXXXXXX-X";


public static void hitScreen(Context context, String label) {

    GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(context);
    Tracker t = analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID);
    t.setScreenName(label);
    t.send(new HitBuilders.AppViewBuilder().build());

}
```

Override OnStart.

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();
    GoogleAnalyticsHits.hitScreen(this,"Screen Name");
}
```

Tryout programmatically as above.

Comment: I still get 09-10 11:15:56.682: W/GAv4(24031): AnalyticsReceiver is not registered or is disabled. Register the receiver for reliable dispatching on non-Google Play devices. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
09-10 11:15:56.693: W/GAv4(24031): CampaignTrackingReceiver is not registered, not exported or is disabled. Installation campaign tracking is not possible. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.
09-10 11:15:56.707: W/GAv4(24031): AnalyticsService not registered in the app manifest. Hits might not be delivered reliably. See http://goo.gl/8Rd3yj for instructions.

Comment: Edited my post. Please check if it is helpful